# How to calculate the area of classified pixels in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, reducers

I'm using the Python API of GEE in a Jupyter notebook.

I'd like to perform a surface evaluation of classified pixels.

I have a `ee_map` with one band called `gfc` that have values in `[1,2 ... 19, 30, 40, 50, 51]` characterising the gain or loss of treecover.

I try to evaluate the surface of each class in hectares:

```py
#define the pixel resolution
    res = 30

    hist = ee_map.reduceRegion(**{
      'reducer': ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
      'geometry': ee.FeatureCollection(assetId).geometry(),
      'scale': res,
      'maxPixels': 1e12
    })

    hist = pd.DataFrame(hist.getInfo()['gfc'])

    #add column name
    hist.columns= ['code', 'pixels'] 

    #won't work 
    #hist['area'] = hist['pixels']*res*res/10000
```

Problem : due to projection issues I don't know the surface of each pixel.
The documentation suggest to use `ee_map.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())` but it will only work if the map have binaries values.

Is there a way to combine it with `ee.Reducer.autoHistogram()` or am I force each of them in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps to this problem :

**Select the values to mask in the band**

perform a hist on your band of interest and you'll obtain a dic of all the unique values and there surface  Keep only the keys in an array

```py
hist = ee_image.select('band').reduceRegion(**{
      'reducer': ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
      'geometry': your_geom, #need to be a geometry
      'maxPixels': 1e12
})
dic = hist.getInfo()['band']
codes = [ dic[i][0] for i in range(len(dic))]
```

fill the `codes` variable directly if you already know your possible values.

**create the surface histogram**

for each value in `codes` create a binary mask for the value. multiply this mask by the pixel surface and then perform a sum. I finally concatenate them in a panda dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd 

columns=['code', 'area_m']
row_list = []
for code in codes:
    code = int(code)
    mask = ee_image.select('band').eq(code)
    mask_surface = mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    stats = mask_surface.reduceRegion(**{
        'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum(),
        'geometry': your_geom,
        'maxPixels': 1e13
    })

    row_list.append({
        columns[0]: code, 
        columns[1]: stats.getInfo()['band']
    })

    
hist = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
```

If anyone knows a more efficient way please feel free to add comments.